# Deleting nodes from LinkedList

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

Just working on better understanding linked list behavior. I feel like this logic is right, but I'm just not getting what's going on. The program is breaking when I hit the point in my main where I am deleting a node from the list. Now that it broke, the "exe" file in my Release folder (VS2013) is now missing and I cant run the program for debugging. IDK what happened there, and I don't know why this isn't working. Any help would be amazing!

When I run this it gets hung up on list1.remove(NODE_TO_REMOVE) and now my debugger cant run the program.

LinkedList.h:

```
class LinkedList
{
protected:
    struct ListNode
    {
        double value;
        ListNode *next;
        ListNode(double value1, ListNode *next1 = NULL)
        {
            value = value1;
            next = next1;
        }
    };
    ListNode *head;
public:
    // Class Constructor(s)
    LinkedList() { head = NULL; }
    LinkedList(const LinkedList &);

    void add(double x);
    void print() const;
    void LinkedList::remove(double value);
private:
};
```

LinkedList.cpp:

```
// Copy Constructor
LinkedList::LinkedList(const LinkedList &object)
{
    head = object.head;
}

void LinkedList::add(double x)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        head = new ListNode(x);
    else
    {
        ListNode *nodePtr = head;
        while (nodePtr->next != NULL)
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        nodePtr->next = new ListNode(x);
    }
}

void LinkedList::print() const
{
    ListNode *nodePtr = head;
    while (nodePtr)
    {
        std::cout << nodePtr->value << ", ";
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
    }
}

void LinkedList::remove(double value)
{
    ListNode *nodePtr = head;
    ListNode *ptrDel = NULL;
    ptrDel = nodePtr;
    while (ptrDel != NULL)
    {
        if (nodePtr->value == value)
        {
            ptrDel = nodePtr;
            nodePtr = ptrDel->next;
            delete ptrDel;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

main:

```
int main()
{
    const double NODE_TO_REMOVE = 15.23;
    const double LIST1_NODES[] = { 67.5, -7.8, NODE_TO_REMOVE, 98.76, -19.45 };
    const double NONEXISTENT_NODE = 45.76;
    const int SIZE = sizeof(LIST1_NODES) / sizeof(LIST1_NODES[0]);

    LinkedList list1;
    LinkedList list3;
    LinkedList list4;

    for (int index = 0; index < SIZE; ++index)
        list1.add(LIST1_NODES[index]);

    cout << "  \"list1\" original: ";
    list1.print();

    //copy constructor test
    LinkedList list2(list1);

    cout << "    \"list2\" original: ";
    list2.print();

    // node removal test:
    list1.remove(NODE_TO_REMOVE);
    cout << "\n      \"list1\" modified:  ";
    list1.print();
    cout << "\n      \"list2\" unchanged: ";
    list2.print();

    cout << endl; 
    system("pause");

    return 0;
```

Comment: You missed to advance `ptrDel = ptrDel->next;` in your `while()` loop in the `LinkedList::remove()` function.

Comment: Not entirely sure why I'm getting downvotes - is my formatting bad? Unclear? I see similar questions but different languages and totally different algorithms for deleting. Mine seems to be breaking my debugger and I'm trying to understand.

Comment: _'Not entirely sure why ...'_ Most probably because you seemingly didn't any debugging efforts and posted too much irrelevant code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not sure what not to post. I deleted the 2-3 methods that arent used in the parts of main I showed. As I mentioned I cant even run the debugger as the "exe" file it creates got deleted after it crashed the first time I ran it. So I'm not sure whats relevant to that crash/deleting of the exe, so I put in most of my code. Sorry

Comment: _'As I mentioned I cant even run the debugger as the "exe" ...'_ That's what the debug build is for?!?

Comment: If I may advise: do NOT use `==` with floating point values (in general); floating point values are *approximate* and depending on how they are obtained and which CPU registers they transit through, they may not always compare equal; instead you need to compare if the two values are "close enough".

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ maybe I'm not explaining myself right (sorry - I'm not an expert by any means) - When I have the project open in VS2013, and I press F5 (or "Debug > Start Debugging") I get an error saying that the project's exe is missing from the Release build. When I go to the Release folder in my project folder, the application exe file that is normally there is not. I do not know what caused this, and it happened only after I tried running this code initially and it hit some type of exception. I can no longer run it to find what exactly went wrong due to the exe being gone.

Comment: When you hit F5 check what project build type is actually selected (Should be 'Debug'), also AFAIR to start up in Debug mode, it was CTRL-F5 IIRC (Choose from the menu if you're not sure about the shortcut).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ctl+F5 is Start Without Debugging. When I change my build type to Debug (Release was selected), it runs but 1) it doesn't delete the node 2) when it hits the end of the program and I press enter to close it, a pop comes up saying: "Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)." it offers Abort, Retry or Ignore. Abort closes it, Retry gets the same thing over and over, and Ignore brings it to an "Unhandled Exception" pop up on output.c

Comment: Seems you're on track now :P ... Sorry for the wrong short cut recommendation, but I'm not working with VS often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking when you want to delete a *node* in a linked list you want to find it first. Assuming you have `data` in that node you want to delete, the **algorithm** is:

1. Point to the `head`
2. loop until you find the node that contains `data`
3. Point the previous node's `next` to the node holding `data` 's `next`
4. now delete the node containing `data`

**note**: You have a special case when the data is in the `head` itself.

in **C++** this is done in the code below:

```
bool deleteNode(datatype data) //True if node found and deleted, false if not found
{
    if(head == 0) return false; //list is empty 

    if(head->next == 0 && head->data == data) //when thge head is the node to be deleted.
    {
        head = 0; //set head to null. This is safer than `delete head;`
        return true;
    }

    node *tmp, *prv;
    tmp = prv = head;

    while(tmp != 0)
    {               
        if(tmp->data == data)
        {
            prv->next = prv->next->next;
            delete tmp;
            return true;
        }
        prv = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

    return false;    
}
```

Comment: Although that direct implementation isn't how I got the delete to work it got me turned onto the right path. Thanks a lot @AK_

Comment: @jacksonSD share with us, I am guessing it was the special case when the data is in `head`? :)